# Simple Query returns error

Tags: android, android-sqlite

This is my Log Cat

```
          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{XXXXXX}: java.lang.IllegalStateException:   Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly   before accessing data from it.
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1960)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1985)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1151)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4482)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:561)
         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from      CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
         at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
         at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:442)
         at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
         at com.gallops.CheckProfile.fillData(CheckProfile.java:171)
         at com.gallops.CheckProfile.onCreate(CheckProfile.java:154)
         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4728)
         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1051)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1924)
         ... 11 more
```

The Query I am trying to Run: 
//DBAdapter file

```
   public Cursor fetchRow(String a) {
            String Key = a; 
            return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE0, new String[] {IDno1, GIDno1,Name1,Owner1,Breed1,Gender1, Notes1,Nature1,Color1,Sire1,Dam1,Height1,Foaled1,Acquired1,Date1,IMG}, "IDno=?",new String[]{Key}, null, null, null, null);
}
```

The function through which I give it a call:

```
           private void fillData() {
    String D = getid();

  Cursor c = DBHelper.fetchRow(IDB);

   // List<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String X = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("IDno")));
            TextView tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            tv2.setText(X);

            String B = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("GIDno")));
            TextView tv6=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7);
            tv6.setText(B);

            String A = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Name")));
            TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv.setText(A);
            NameTop = A; 

            String Y = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Owner")));
            TextView tv12=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView13);
            tv12.setText(Y);

            String G = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Breed")));
            TextView tv10=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView11);
            tv10.setText(G);

            String N = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Notes")));
            TextView tv8=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView9);
            tv8.setText(N);

            String da = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Dam")));
            TextView tv14=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
            tv14.setText(da);

            String si = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Sire")));
            TextView tv16=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView04);
            tv16.setText(si);

            String co = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Color")));
            TextView tv18=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView06);
            tv18.setText(co);


            String g = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Gender")));
            TextView tv20=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView08);
            tv20.setText(g);


            String na = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Nature")));
            TextView tv22=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView10);
            tv22.setText(na);


            String he = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Height")));
            TextView tv24=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView12);
            tv24.setText(he);


            String fo = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Foaled")));
            //TextView tv26=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView14);
            //tv26.setText(fo);


            String ac = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Acquired")));
            TextView tv28=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView16);
            tv28.setText(ac);

           /*Dt = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Date")));
            int age = age(Dt);
            TextView Tvx =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            String DD = Integer.toString(age);
            Tvx.setText(DD); */

            Image = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("image"));

            if (Image!=null){
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(Image, 0, Image.length, options); 
                    ImageView Img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                    Img.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
            }else{
                ImageView Img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                Img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic); 
            }

        } while (c.moveToNext());
        DBHelper.close();

    } 
}
```

Comment: Don't close your database inside the if clause . Close it out of the `if (c.moveToFirst()) {}` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Declare a Cursor globally in your actvity

Cursor datacursor;

```
 And then assign to datacursor instead of c.

 datacursor = DBHelper.fetchRow(IDB);
```

Access the row using `datacursor`

Comment: Tried this one too, I will report back if I face this problem again. Thanks for the help. Though I wonder how this can change the way I am populating the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Your probably going to want to write some debug lines that output to logcat to make sure that your actually getting information in your cursor and that you are getting the information you think you should be.

You also need to check that there the cursor is not null before you try to use data from it. If the cursor is null, the app will crash. I learned that the hard way. You can check for a null cursor using:

```
if(cu != null && cu.getCount() > 0){
    cu.moveToFirst();
    // The rest of your code
}
```

Comment: This error is thrown only on some instances when I query, for other fields in the database (the rows) it works fine. Only in some cases does this pop up, plus I am sure of having data in the database as I can see it in SQLite browser.

Comment: I had data in my database too, but sometimes my SQL wasn't returning what I thought it was. Just something helpful to keep in mind for future reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot matey I will implement this :)